# Assets fails to precompile after first deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I am using capistrano for deployment, after running

> cap deploy:cold

works just fine.
 but if i run

> cap deploy

after running cold deploy

it trows an error saying

```
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * 2013-01-01 11:55:29 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/poploda/releases/20130101105518 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["192.34.56.129"]
    [192.34.56.129] executing command
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] Killed
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] 
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] (in /home/deployer/apps/poploda/releases/20130101105518/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:142:in `exec_runtime'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-1.3.0/lib/uglifier.rb:100:in `compile'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `block in js_compressor='
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `each'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:19:in `block in compile'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:219:in `block in each_logical_path'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:206:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:196:in `each_entry'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:204:in `block in each_file'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:203:in `each_file'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:217:in `each_logical_path'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] 9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] /home/deployer/apps/poploda/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
 ** [out :: 192.34.56.129] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 82944ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/poploda/releases/20130101105518; true"
    servers: ["192.34.56.129"]
    [192.34.56.129] executing command
    command finished in 2658ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/poploda/releases/20130101105518 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on 192.34.56.129
```

my cap deploy script is

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "whenever/capistrano"

server "192.34.56.129", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "poploda"
set :user, "deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:ramza1/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config/environments"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    put File.read("config/environments/production.example.rb"), "#{shared_path}/config/environments/production.rb"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/environments/production.rb #{release_path}/config/environments/production.rb"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"


  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

any help thanks.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue? I am encountering the same problem after deploy:cold.  I dont know why its referencing Ruby 1.9.1 when I have 1.9.3 installed using rbenv.

Comment: yes. all i had to do was upgrade my ram to a minimum of 512mb

Answer (score 1):

Does your server have `ExecJS` runtime? If not then, install one of the compatible runtimes

Comment: It works wen I run cap deploy:cold then After a simple update and I run cap deploy it fails

Comment: This helped me get it working. Added the execjs and rubyracer gem and got it working.